# How to go to the previous page in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the code to allow the user to get back to the previous page?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depends what you consider to be *back* I guess. Previous page the user visited, or is there a sequential flow to your page?

Comment: I would love to implement a sequential flow, but at the moment there is no time for that. It's okay to get to the previous page visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script>
  function goBack()
  {
    window.history.back()
  }
</script>

<body>
  <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</body>
```

(from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript

```
history.back()
```

You can return it from action:

```
public ActionResult Back()
{
    return this.JavaScript("<script>history.back();</script>")
}
```

Comment: I was surprise too ... it's not working I tested it and had the same result

Comment: This solution gave me a blank page, strange that many upvoted it.